# Embedded controllers in Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Is there any possibility how to call controller inside Blade template?
I’m rewriting my app from Symfony framework to Laravel, but Symfony's Twig allows me to show dynamic data in layout view by using [embedded controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers), so I can keep things DRY.
Is there any alternative to embedded controllers in Laravel? Otherwise I'd have to set common data explicitly for every view.

Comment: Calling controllers from Views is not that wise, because it adds dependencies inside them towards your controllers. Controllers should be only collection information and deciding about the Views, normally a helper will help you out with things you might need to do.
What exactly do you need to do in your view that a Controller is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for View Composers.

From the documentation:

> View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a
>   view is rendered. If you have data that you want bound to a given view
>   each time that view is rendered throughout your application, a view
>   composer can organize that code into a single location. Therefore,
>   view composers may function like "view models" or "presenters".

http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers

Comment: Suppose that we have a simple ecommerce application with standard sites like home, products list (search results), product show and so on and we want to show the categories menu on every single site. With View Composers we have to "whitelist" each view which need's categories data. If number of these sites is big, do it in this way is cumbersome I think... and the developer must always remember to put new view name to that list, if he created one that needs categories data