# Laravel render\call controller action from view\layout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, render, partial

Maybe someone can tell me how to use something like embedded controllers in [symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers), to call\render controller action in Laravel4,5?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815634/embedded-controllers-in-blade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the best way for me, for L5:

**CartServerProvider**

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CartServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

  /**
   * Register the service provider.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function register()
  {
    $this->app->make('view')->composer('layouts.master', 'Vendor\Cart\Http\ViewComposers\CartComposer');
  }

}
```

The **CartComposer** class looks like this:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;

class CartComposer {

  /**
   * Cart manager instance.
   *
   * @var \Vendor\Cart\StoreInterface
   */
  protected $cart;

  /**
   * Create a new CartComposer instance.
   */
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->cart = app()->make('cart.store');
  }

  /**
   * Compose the view.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function compose(View $view)
  {
    $view->with('cart', $this->cart);
  }

}
```

**cart.store** is a custom cart implementation I injected into the container, but the above should be enough to show you how to register a simple view composer.